# Flex Slider image height

Tags: css, flexslider

I have a problem with slider on my page. The size of images is 1020x340 and for slider I use width: 78%; . I want to set to my slider a specific height because him cut the picture.. it`s less than 340.

```
 .flexslider {padding: 0;}
 .flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} 
 .flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block; min-height: 340px;}


.flexslider {
width: 78%; /*85%*/
margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
}

.flexslider .slides {
   height: 340px;
}
```

And here is flexslider.js - http://goo.gl/cAytX7